# Is it possible to convert BAM file from one genome assembly to the other?

Tags: sam, genome, assembly

I Have multiple BAM files that are referenced to UCSC genome assembly GRCh37/hg19 that are read in different time frames. Now, I am planning a different studies that require assembling all the data against one assembly. Will it be possible to convert all the BAM files that I have to an upgraded version or convert the assembly to a different new assembly and how?
I am new in this and not a bioinformatician so, if you have any questions regarding my question to answer you can ask, any type of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, with tools like [CrossMap](https://crossmap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but my recommendation is to re-align. Assemblies can change a lot between versions and your reads will undoubdedly align differently. Re-aligning is cheap, it will take a few days and you're good. Re-doing your analysis because you realize the coordinate translation messed something up will cost you much more time and energy.